# Facebook "like" doesn't post on timeline

Tags: facebook

I want to have a "Like" Facebook button on my WordPress page. I tried using both plugins and straight code from the Facebook docs. Both work, but my "likes" don't publish on my timeline. I did put my AppID there, what can it be?

fb-root code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=###"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`
```

fb:like code:

```
<fb:like href="<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>`
```

Comment: You have to show some code/jsfiddle what you have - otherwise its pretty hard to help you - You also have [Facebook Lint for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to help you debug

Comment: Code is pretty straightforward, just `fb-root`:
`<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=###";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`
and `fb:like`:
`<fb:like href="<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>`

Comment: Please edit the code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Activity Log on Facebook to see if the 'Like' has shown up on your profile. The Like may have been posted as 'Recent Activity' or as a individual 'Someone has liked ...' post.

Comment: I am having a similare issue but, as Niraj mentioned, my "likes" are showing up in the users 'Recent Activity', but not in their Timeline. How can I make them appear in the Timeline?

Comment: If you want to move them from Recent Activity to the Timeline, click on the Edit icon next to the activity in the Activity Log and click on "Show on timeline". That will move it on your timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Facebook debugger to lint your site/page where the like button resides:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

This will tell you if you have any issues with the like button and or the OG tags on the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It returns error "Object Invalid Value" about "website" object. But I don't know how to fix it. We're using some kind of premium theme, could that be the reason?

Comment: It certainly could be the issue. I would investigate open graph tags on the page. A good reference is here : http://ogp.me/ -- this will get you the basic setup that you would need for a like button.

Comment: Is using Open Graph necessary?

Comment: Using the open graph tags is if you want a proper like to show up in the stream of users. But, no, not necessarily. Can I ask what the url of a page is for your site?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample of your html should look like.

*Some Tip for you, dont simply like your page if you not sure your website format is correct, because it will submit a record to facebook with wrong title/images/description/content and etc.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
<title>WooTube</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="WooTube"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.wootube.woolei.com"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/LD-rmC2i624/default.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="WooTube"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="568394401"/>
<meta property="og:description"
      content="WooTube - Share Video To All Your FaceBook Group With 1 Click!"/>
 </head>
 <body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to submit your Facebook app for review before "likes" will appear in user's timelines, via Facebook's App Dashboard >> Status & Review >> Start a Submission:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm a bit late :) but given I don't see an accepted answer...

Are you able to see the right Like count from the [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)?

If not, probably worth to verify that the outcome of the following code represent the right URL (and with a proper encoding):

```
<fb:like href="<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>
```